# Ошибка при удаление сторок по условию: KeyError: "['False'] not found in axis"

Tags: python, pandas

Есть таблица:

[image: Таблица для Pandas]

Нужно удалить все строки содержащие `False`:

```
df1.drop('False',axis=0)
```

Пробовал миллиард разных вариантов.

Выдает ошибку типа:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-232-ffe16d70a760> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 df1.drop('False',axis=0)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   5282         if mask.any():
   5283             if errors != "ignore":
-> 5284                 raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
   5285             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   5286         return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: "['False'] not found in axis"
```

Comment: Зачем их удалять? Можно сделать подвыборку же.

Comment: Я хочу их удалить и обогатить данными таблицу.

Comment: `df = df[df['check']]`

Comment: А если я хочу удалить **дддд** из **SKU**

Comment: df = df[df['SKU'] != 'дддд']

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов - спасибо, я понял свою ошибку

Answer (score 3):

Судя по примеру данных на картинке, в столбце `check` у вас строки со значениями `"FALSE"` и `"TRUE"`, поэтому и работать нужно как со строками:

```
res = df.query("check == 'TRUE'")
```

чтобы дополнительно удалить `SKU == 'ддд'`:

```
res = df.query("check == 'TRUE' and SKU not in ('ддд')")
```

Comment: pandas может перевести в True/False

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов, перевести конечно можно, но я не знаю зачем автор вопроса создал этот столбец как строку... Может быть это просто пример данных в вопросе , набранный ручками ;)

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли, когда он считает данные, может неявно преобразовать, я правда не знаю, что именно тут случится, но у меня строки true/false легко парсит из sql'а

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов, по-моему `df[df['check']]` отработает совсем не так как вы ожидаете если `check` - это строковой столбец

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что не так. Я имею в виду, что если они лежат в csv'шке, то при чтении они могут неявно преобразоваться.

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов, я вопросе не видел упоминаний CSV... ;)